# highest of 4 numbers by conditional operater

Tags: c++, conditional-operator, highest

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   int a,b,c,Highest;
     cout<<"Enter three numbers:";
     cin>>a>>b>>c;
       Highest=(a>b&&a>c?a:b>c?b:c);
       cout<<"Highest is:"<<Highest;

    return 0;
}
```

*I know how to find out largest of 3 numbers by using conditional operator.BUt How to find out highest of 4 numbers by using conditional operator in c+ ???
anyone can help me out ??*

Comment: Using the ternary operator for this will make code unreadable, but if you have to use it (as part of whatever assignment you have) just use more of it.

Comment: you mean something ugly like: a>b&&a>c&&a>d?a:b>c&&b>d?b:c>d?c:d
good gods!

Comment: `std::max(a, std::max(b, std::max(c, d)));`

Comment: @arunmu It is a smart method but not the conditional operator.

Comment: You can make it a little more readable by using intermediate results and simpler ternary operations like `a > b ? a : b`. Then use the intermediate results the same way, until you have a single max value. And remember that the number of expressions can be shortened because if `a > b && b > c` then that implies `a > c` is true as well.

Answer (score 1):

To me the question isn't great, as a way to when learn how to do this.

I would instead ask how to find the highest of three numbers - using the knowledge of how to find the highest of two numbers, and then build on that.

As @Some-programmer-dude indicate this will use intermediate results:

```
  int highest = a>b ? a : b;
  highest = highest>c ? highest : c;
  highest = highest>d ? highest : d;
```

or if you want parallelism:

```
int hFirstPart = a>b ? a : b;
int hSecondPart = c>d ? c : d;
int highest = hFirstPart>hSecondPart? hFirstPart : hSecondPart;
```

Answer (score 0):

Place them into a vector and use `std::max_element`:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
int tmp;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    std::cin >> tmp;
    vec.push_back(tmp);
}
int max = *std::max_element(vec.begin(), vec.end());
std::cout << max << std::endl;
```

Comment: Or in C++11: `std::max({a,b,c,d})`

Comment: @DanAllen Good to know that we have this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Highest=(a>b&&a>c&&a>d?a:b>c&&b>d?b:c>d&c:d);
```

This code is pretty unreadable so better to expand it using a set of consequent `if` clauses.

Answer (score -3):

Below code will work for any number of elements, just replace SIZE with the desired number of elements.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define SIZE 4

int GetMax(int[], int, int, int);

int main()
{

   int a[SIZE];
   int i=0;

   while(i < SIZE)
   {
       cout << "Enter input " << i+1 << " : ";
       cin >> a[i++];
   }

   cout << "Highest = " << GetMax(a, 0, SIZE, a[0]) << endl;

   return 0;
}

int GetMax(int a[], int i, int n, int max)
{
    return ( i < n-1) ? GetMax(a, i+1, n, (a[i] > max ? a[i] : max)) :  a[i] > max ? a[i] : max;
}
```

Comment: Try entering -4, -1, -3, -10. What does it print?  What should it print?

Comment: Also consider using `return i == 0? max : GetMax(a+1,i-i, (a[0] > max ? a[0] : max);`